# Convert a structured string to a tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have strings formatted like this `cookie,sandwich(hotdog,burger),cake(chocolate(tiramisu)),candy`. I'd like to convert into a tree-like structure (can be hash/array):

```
cookie
sandwich
|__hotdog
|__burger
cake
|__chocolate
   |__tiramisu
candy
```

What's the simplest way to do this? I looked at Treetop but it seems overkill.

Comment: Any time there is a tree involved, recursion is your friend.

Comment: I believe this is a pure-Ruby question, in which case you should not have a Rails tag.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "cookie,sandwich(hotdog,burger(cheese,onions)),cake(chocolate(tiramisu)),candy"
```

Let's first create a helper method to split strings on those commas that are separated by strings containing balanced parentheses.

```
def separate(str)
  start_idx = 0
  left_paren_count = 0
  str.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) do |(c,i),a|
    case c
    when '('
      left_paren_count += 1
    when ')'
      left_paren_count -= 1
    when ','
      if left_paren_count.zero?
        a << str[start_idx..i-1]
        start_idx = i+1
      end
    end
  end  << str[start_idx..-1]
end
```

For example,

```
separate(str)
  #=> ["cookie",
  #    "sandwich(hotdog,burger(cheese,onions))",
  #    "cake(chocolate(tiramisu))",
  #    "candy"]
```

```
separate("hotdog,burger(cheese,onions)")
  #=> ["hotdog",
  #    "burger(cheese,onions)"]
```

```
separate("cheese,onions")
  #=> ["cheese", "onions"]
```

We may now write a recursive expression.

```
def recurse(str)
  separate(str).map do |s,h|
    s1, s2 = s.split('(', 2)
    s.include?('(') ? [s1, recurse(s2[0..-2])] : s1
  end
end
```

Try it.

```
recurse(str)
  #=> ["cookie",
  #   ["sandwich", ["hotdog", ["burger", ["cheese", "onions"]]]],
  #   ["cake", [["chocolate", ["tiramisu"]]]], "candy"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
class Node
  attr_reader :name
  attr_reader :children

  def initialize(str)
    @name, children_str = str.match(/^(\w+)\((.+)\)$/)&.captures
    nodes = (children_str || str)
            .scan(/(\w+\([\w,]+\))|(\w+\([\w,()]+\))|(\w+)/)
            .flatten.compact
    if @name.nil? && nodes.size == 1
      @name = nodes.first
    else
      @children = nodes.map { |s|
        Node.new(s)
      }
    end
  end

  def show_tree(level=0)
    str = ""
    unless @name.nil?
      str =  "   " * (level - 1) if level > 1
      str += "|__" if level > 0
      str += "#{@name}\n"
      level += 1
    end
    @children&.each do |node|
      str += "#{node.show_tree(level)}"
    end
    str
  end
end
```

test

```rb
foods = Node.new("cookie,sandwich(hotdog,burger),cake(chocolate(tiramisu)),candy")
puts foods.show_tree
# cookie
# sandwich
# |__hotdog
# |__burger
# cake
# |__chocolate
#    |__tiramisu
# candy

rails = Node.new("root(config,db(migrate,seeds),lib,app(controllers(concerns,api),models(concerns),views))")
puts rails.show_tree
# root
# |__config
# |__db
#    |__migrate
#    |__seeds
# |__lib
# |__app
#    |__controllers
#       |__concerns
#       |__api
#    |__models
#       |__concerns
#    |__views
```